# Flutter padding, margin and alginment best practices

Tags: flutter

What is the best practice in flutter for padding,margin etc.

example:

I made a simple drawer in flutter. To make everything to position in places I want. I used padding extensively.

Now the issue is when I test it on different phone of different size. the positions are inconsistent across different devices.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Flutter [Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html):

> Design discussion Why use a Padding widget rather than a Container
> with a Container.padding property? There isn't really any difference
> between the two. If you supply a Container.padding argument, Container
> simply builds a Padding widget for you.
>
> Container doesn't implement its properties directly. Instead,
> Container combines a number of simpler widgets together into a
> convenient package. For example, the Container.padding property causes
> the container to build a Padding widget and the Container.decoration
> property causes the container to build a DecoratedBox widget. If you
> find Container convenient, feel free to use it. If not, feel free to
> build these simpler widgets in whatever combination meets your needs.
>
> In fact, the majority of widgets in Flutter are simply combinations of
> other simpler widgets. Composition, rather than inheritance, is the
> primary mechanism for building up widgets.

So, no worries about padding widgets.
A good practice to get some spaces inside a `Column()` or `Row()` is using `SizedBox()`. Then you add an extra space setting up width or height.